# Rewriting continued fraction for spheroidal eigenvalue function $\lambda_{n,m}(z)$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, special-functions, inverse-function, continued-fractions, transcendental-equations

I know little about spheroidal functions and browsing Wolfram functions, the [**Spheroidal Eigenvalue function $\lambda_{n,m}(z)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/MathieuandSpheroidalFunctions/SpheroidalEigenvalue/03/) was intriguing. According to the DLMF section [30.3(iii)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/30.3#E5):

> $$b_p-\lambda-\frac{a_{p-2}c_p}{b_{p-2}-\lambda-} \frac{a_{p-4}c_{p-2}}{b_{p-4}-\lambda-}\cdots= \frac{a_pc_{p+2}}{b_{p+2}-\lambda-} \frac{a_{p+2}c_{p+4}}{b_{p+4}-\lambda-}\cdots\\a_k=-(k+1)(k+2),b_k=(m+k)(m+k+1)-c^2,c_k=c^2$$
> If $p$ is even, then $\lambda=\lambda_{m+2\Bbb N,m}(c^2)$ and if $p$ is odd, then $\lambda=\lambda_{m+2\Bbb N+1,m}(c^2)$

Using [continued fraction K notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html):

$$b_p-\lambda-\frac{a_{p-2}c_p}{b_{p-2}-\lambda-}\cdots \frac{a_{p-2t}c_{p-2(t-1)}}{b_{p-2t}-\lambda-}\cdots= \frac{a_pc_{p+2}}{b_{p+2}-\lambda-} \cdots\frac{a_{p+2(t-1)}c_{p+2t}}{b_{p+2t}-\lambda-} \cdots\\ b_p-\lambda-\mathop{\text K}_{t=1}^\infty \frac{-a_{p-2t}c_{p-2(t-1)}}{b_{p-2t}-\lambda}= \mathop{\text K}_{t=1}^\infty  \frac{-a_{p+2(t-1)}c_{p+2t}}{b_{p+2t}-\lambda}\\(m+p)(m+p+1)-c^2-\lambda-\mathop{\text K}_{t=1}^\infty \frac{(p-2t+1)(p-2t+2)c^2}{(m+p-2t)(m+p-2t+1)-c^2-\lambda}= \mathop{\text K}_{t=1}^\infty \frac{(p+2t-1)(p+2t)c^2}{(m+p+2t)(m+p+2t+1)-c^2-\lambda} $$

Hopefully this expansion is correct. If it is, then there is [no closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContinuedFractionK%5B+%28p%2B2k-1%29%28p%2B2k%29c%2C%28%28m%2Bp%2B2k%29%28m%2Bp%2B2k%2B1%29-c-y%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D). Similarly, papers like [this one with formula $(A.3)$](https://escholarship.org/content/qt5672n8n6/qt5672n8n6.pdf) define a new function for the continued fraction.

However, a special case of the spheroidal eigenvalue function are the [Mathieu characteristics](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+MathieuCharacteristicA+vs+MathieuCharacteristicB) which gives the inverse of the [Mathieu characteristic exponent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+MathieuCharacteristicexponent), which is not the argument of a Mathieu function. The continued fractions may be expressible in terms of a general special function.

It is definable using the [angular spheroidal function of the first kind $\text{PS}_{n,m}(c,z)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/MathieuandSpheroidalFunctions/SpheroidalPS/20/01/01/), [its derivative wrt $z$](https://functions.wolfram.com/MathieuandSpheroidalFunctions/SpheroidalPS/20/01/01/0001/) from [this formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/MathieuandSpheroidalFunctions/SpheroidalPS/20/01/01/0002/), and similar ones from other spheroidal functions:

$$\frac{2z\text{PS}’_{n,m}(c,z)-(1-z^2)\text{PS}’’_{n,m}(c,z)}{\text{PS}_{n,m}(c,z)}-(1-z^2)c^2+\frac{m^2}{1-z^2} =\lambda_{n,m}(c)$$

but then we need to know what $\frac{d^2\text{PS}_{n,m}(c,z)}{dz^2}$ is.

**Special Cases:**

$$x^3-8x^2+4(4c^2+3)x-64c^2=0\implies x=\lambda_{n,3}(c),n=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$$
[partly shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bx%5E3-8x%5E2%2B4%284e%5E2%2B3%29x-64e%5E2%2C20%5D%2Cx%3Dspheroidaleigenvalue%281%2C3%2Ce%29)

We can find other equations $\lambda_{n,m}(z)$ solves for general $n,m,z$, but to narrow down:

What is a special case, closed form, or integral/sum form of the continued fraction?